# My VBA IF statement is generation a compile error

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement

There is something wrong with my code and I can't seem to find it so I need another pair of eyes I think I'm going VBA Blind.

This is my code very simple if someone is doing a higher level then 3 columns are greyed out and n/a as they wont be getting any results for those modules in column D, F and G. If there not doing the higher level then it would be a reversed and they wont be getting results for modules in column B, C and E.  There are 28 trainees so it would need to work for all rows.

The current code is as follows:

```vb
Private Sub Update()
    Dim Course As String
    Dataset = Range("A").Value

    If Course = "Higher" Then
        Range("D").Value = "N/A"
        Range("F").Value = "N/A"
        Range("G").Value = "N/A"
        Range("D,F,G").Select

        With Selection.Interior
            .Pattern = xlSolid
            .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
            .TintAndShade = -0.249977111117893
            .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    Else
            Range("B").Value = "N/A"
            Range("C").Value = "N/A"
            Range("E").Value = "N/A"
            Range("B,C,E").Select

            With Selection.Interior
                .Pattern = xlSolid
                .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
                .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
                .TintAndShade = -0.249977111117893
                .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End If
            End With

End Sub
```

However, I getting a compile error saying "Else without and If".  As far as I can tell all the variables are declared the `IF` statement has been structured correctly.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Can you see it now that it's indented accordingly?

Comment: It amazes me how many questions are asked because of incosistent indentation...

Comment: `With` starts in between `IF .. Then` and `Else` and ends after `End If`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Private Sub Update()
    Dim Course As String
    Dataset = Range("A").Value

    If Course = "Higher" Then
        Range("D").Value = "N/A"
        Range("F").Value = "N/A"
        Range("G").Value = "N/A"
        Range("D,F,G").Select

        With Selection.Interior
            .Pattern = xlSolid
            .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
            .TintAndShade = -0.249977111117893
            .PatternTintAndShade = 0
        End With
    Else
            Range("B").Value = "N/A"
            Range("C").Value = "N/A"
            Range("E").Value = "N/A"
            Range("B,C,E").Select

            With Selection.Interior
                .Pattern = xlSolid
                .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
                .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
                .TintAndShade = -0.249977111117893
                .PatternTintAndShade = 0
            End With
    End If

End Sub
```

If comes down to:

```
If ... Then
  ...
  With ...     'Start the first With-clause
    ...
  End With     'End the first With-clause
Else           'All With-clauses need to be closed before you can go here
  ...
  With ...     'Start the second With-clause
    ...
  End With     'End the second With-clause
End If         'All With-clauses needed be closed before you can go here.
```

Comment: While technically valid, that's a poor fix. It misses that the contents of the `with`s is identical, that there is [no need to select](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10714251/11683) and that the other actions too are the same, just applied to different ranges.

Comment: @GSerg: some things are selected, and nothing is done with them after all. That's indeed wrong, but it was my attempt to solve the compilation error first.

Comment: ...which results now to an accepted answer using `Select` and `Selection`, plus unqualified ranges, plus duplicate code - best way to generate new newbie questions.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 `With` statements and only 1 `End With`.

Either move your `With Selection.Interior` above the first `If` and remove the second `With`.

or

Move your last `End With` above the `End If`.

Comment: There are indeed 2 `With` statements and only 1 `End With`, which is not the only problem with that code. The first of the two "either" would fix it, the second won't.